# Why am I getting "The page has expired due to inactivity." on my API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

I'm trying to use Postman to POST a Json in my API but I'm getting an error:

> The page has expired due to inactivity.

So, in the Postman I'm accessing http://localhost:8000/api/jobs/ . In my Headers tab, I'm using Content-type as key and application/json as value and inserting the following JSON:

```
{"title": "PHP Developer / Laravel Expert","description": "Laravel Expert", "local": "São Paulo", "remote": "no", "company_id": "3"}
```

I'm using laravel.
Here is my web.php route file:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Jobs API', 'status' => 'Connected']);
});

Route::resource('jobs', 'JobsController');
Route::resource('companies', 'CompaniesController');
```

});

And here is my store method on CompaniesController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $job = new Job();
    $job->fill($request->all());
    $job->save();

    return response()->json($job, 201);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using **laravel version > 5.3** Instead of writing API routes in web.php write your api route in api.php in Route folder.

> The api.php file contains routes that the RouteServiceProvider places in the api middleware group, which provides rate limiting. These routes are intended to be stateless, so requests entering the application through these routes are intended to be authenticated via tokens and will not have access to session state.

[Route Directory in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/structure#the-routes-directory)

Answer (score 2):

If you have laravel 5.5 and wanted to remove that csrf protection from a route, then you could add it to `$except = [];` in App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.

You'll probably want to put some other form of authentication in place, though.

Answer (score 0):

You must include middleware in your route

```
'middleware' => 'api'
```